# How to put background image to the plot in Rust plotters lib

Tags: plot, rust, background-image

I'm trying to draw car trips on a plane. I'm using Plotters library.
Here is some code example of trips' drawing procedure:

```rust
pub fn save_trips_as_a_pic<'a>(trips: &CarTrips, resolution: (u32, u32))
{
   // Some initializing stuff 
   /// <...>

    let root_area =
        BitMapBackend::new("result.png", (resolution.0, resolution.1)).into_drawing_area();

    root_area.fill(&WHITE).unwrap();

    let root_area =
        root_area.margin(10,10,10,10).titled("TITLE",
                         ("sans-serif", 20).into_font()).unwrap();

    let drawing_areas =
        root_area.split_evenly((cells.1 as usize, cells.0 as usize));

    for (index, trip) in trips.get_trips().iter().enumerate(){

        let mut chart =
            ChartBuilder::on(drawing_areas.get(index).unwrap())
            .margin(5)
            .set_all_label_area_size(50)
            .build_ranged(50.0f32..54.0f32, 50.0f32..54.0f32).unwrap();

        chart.configure_mesh().x_labels(20).y_labels(10)
            .disable_mesh()
            .x_label_formatter(&|v| format!("{:.1}", v))
            .y_label_formatter(&|v| format!("{:.1}", v))
            .draw().unwrap();

        let coors = trip.get_points();
        {
            let draw_result =
                chart.draw_series(series_from_coors(&coors, &BLACK)).unwrap();

            draw_result.label(format!("TRIP {}",index + 1)).legend(
                move |(x, y)|
                PathElement::new(vec![(x, y), (x + 20, y)], &random_color));
        }
        {
            // Here I put red dots to see exact nodes
            chart.draw_series(points_series_from_trip(&coors, &RED));
        }
        
        chart.configure_series_labels().border_style(&BLACK).draw().unwrap();
    }
}
```

What I got now on Rust Plotters:

[image: What I got now on Rust Plotters]

So, after drawing it in the 'result.png' image file, I struggle to understand these "lines", because I don't see the map itself. I suppose, there is some way in this library to put a map "map.png" in the background of the plot. If I would use Python, this problem will be solved like this:

```py
# here we got a map image;
img: Image.Image = Image.open("map-image.jpg")
img.putalpha(64)
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
# let's pretend that we got our map size in pixels and coordinates
# just in right relation to each other.
scale = 1000
x_shift = 48.0
y_shift = 50.0
coor_a = Coordinate(49.1, 50.4)
coor_b = Coordinate(48.9, 51.0)

x_axis = [coor_a.x, coor_b.x]
x_axis = [(element-x_shift) * scale for element in x_axis]
y_axis = [coor_a.y, coor_b.y]
y_axis = [(element-y_shift) * scale for element in y_axis]

plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis, marker='o')
plt.show()
```

[Desired result on Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNuDv.png)

Well, that's easy on Python, but I got no idea, how to do similar thing on Rust.

Comment: The `plotters` docs include an [`example`](https://github.com/38/plotters/blob/master/examples/blit-bitmap.rs) for drawing an image on a chart…